# VBA Excel - Setting Chart data from memory

Tags: excel, vba

In Excel, via VBA, is it possible to set chart data from data that is held in memory?  For example, if you created an array in VBA [1,2,3,4,5,6...], can you have a chart in the workbook display that?

Thanks - KC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, here's a simple example...

```
Sub test()

    Dim vXVals As Variant
    Dim vVals As Variant

    vXVals = Array("Wk1", "Wk2", "Wk3")
    vVals = Array(100, 175, 150)

    With ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=Range("B2").Left, Top:=Range("B2").Top, Width:=360, Height:=210).Chart
        With .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
            .Name = "Series Name"
            .XValues = vXVals
            .Values = vVals
        End With
    End With

End Sub
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Immensely!  I was worried it would be some super complicated memory / keeping data objects in scope thing.... Thanks!

Comment: One follow up question - do you know if there is a way to append data to that chart later on without providing it with the entire array again?  The array that I'm initially setting it to will take some time to run, but would like to append incoming data as it comes in.

Comment: Got it - test = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Values

Comment: That's great, glad you were able to figure out the last part.  Cheers!

Comment: Sorry, I guess that wasn't really a complete answer eh!  I figured I'd just get the existing values from the chart using that line above, add a row to the array, and set the Chart.Values property again

Comment: Once you've assigned the existing values to your array variable, as you've already shown, increase the size of the variable by using `Redim Preserve`, add your new values to the array, and then re-assign the array  to the Values property for your series.