# Hide chart data by putting it into vba

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table with 3 columns and 25 rows and there is a chart based on this data.
Now what I **have** to do is, take this table and somehow hard code it into vba, so its nowhere in the excel sheets.

Do you have any advise? I saw that you can create and modify charts with vba code, but they always do it with data from the sheets, they don't store the data in vba itself.

For me this makes no sense either, but it's a thing I **have** to do. 
I myself would simply hide the colums or sheet.

Comment: Why do you *have* to do it that way?

Comment: Because I was told to. I said it doesn't make any sense but I was told to still try it. So I am asking here, because I don't think it will work, but maybe there is a workaround or something like that.

Comment: @BigBen Chart can be made out of an array. User will have to put all the values in an array in vba without input referred to cells. ... refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45525369/vba-excel-setting-chart-data-from-memory... This kind of chart will appear only on running the macro :)

Comment: @Naresh - good find! I stand corrected - but I still really *wouldn't* do this :-)

Comment: @BigBen  I don't think anybody will want to do this.. May be the user wants to hide data for some reason :).. But good to learn.

Comment: @Naresh - yep! Completely agree. The "I wouldn't do this" was for OP. Again, thanks for the find!

Comment: Thank you, this helps me a lot! The chart I have to draw is a lot more complicated, but one step at a time :-)

Comment: Consider putting the data on a Very Hidden Sheet. People who think data is obfuscated because its in code will probably not be able to find said sheet or make it visible